# runtime of using [::-1] on a list

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

prepping for interviews and this is something i couldnt find. [https://blog.finxter.com/python-list-reverse/#:~:text=The%20time%20complexity%20of%20the,the%20number%20of%20list%20elements](https://blog.finxter.com/python-list-reverse/#:%7E:text=The%20time%20complexity%20of%20the,the%20number%20of%20list%20elements). says .reverse() is the O(n) which I assume is because it replaces every index. is [::-1] just printing the list backwards or is something similar going on

Comment: What does "replaces every index" mean? I've probably been doing this too long, but I'm having trouble imagining how you would do this in *not* O(n), so I'm not clear on what you're asking

Comment: "is [::-1] just printing the list backwards"—No, [::1] isn't printing anything: it's slicing a list backwards to create a new list.

Comment: my question is if using [::-1] is the same list in memory just read from the end to the front. if [::-1] returns a copy then it is an O(n) operation but if is just returning the same array in memory with a different reference point then there is no operation done to the array like .reverse() does where the elements of the array are replaced with each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.reverse` operates in place. That means that it almost certainly does something like this under the hood:

```
for i in range(len(self) // 2):
     j = len(self) - 1 - i
     self[i], self[j] = self[j], self[i]
```

The actual method is implemented in C, so of course it will be much more verbose, especially in the swapping operation.

`list[::-1]` creates a copy of the original. The idea is similar, but since the reversal of not in place, you have the luxury of just writing to a destination index rather than swapping via a temporary object:

```
new = [None] * len(self)
for i in range(len(self)):
    j = len(self) - 1 - i
    new[j] = self[i]
```

The actual slice processing code is much more complex since it has to be able to accept integers and all sorts of unorthodox slice expressions that set custom start and stop bounds, and step sizes.

Comment: appreciate it. your reply helped me realize what I was actually trying to figure out. if [::-1] was the same array or a copy

Comment: @wetmoney.  I suggest selecting an answer :)

Comment: funny reading this back